# _tkinter.TclError: Layout PViewStyle not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

I am having trouble defining a Style for my Treeview widget.

```
newT=ttk.Style() 
newT.configure('PViewStyle', rowheight=100) 
PatrolView = ttk.Treeview(PatrolOverview,style='PViewStyle')
```

but this yields

```
_tkinter.TclError: Layout PViewStyle not found
```

Comment: The name of the Style follows the rule `PViewStyle.Treeview`. Means must end with `.Treeview`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get same error :). The problem is that name style must be end to correct name style in tkinter

***Widget class Style name***

Button  TButton
Checkbutton TCheckbutton
Combobox    TCombobox
Entry   TEntry
...
**Treeview  Treeview (not TTreview!)**
https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-style-layer.html

In your case you need to name your style as **PViewStyle.Treeview**
Change our code to:

```
newT=ttk.Style() 
newT.configure('PViewStyle.Treeview', rowheight=100) 
PatrolView = ttk.Treeview(PatrolOverview,style='PViewStyle.Treeview')
```